# Rotate surfaceview according to display orientation

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, screen-orientation

I am facing a problem while writing a camera application.
My layout is something like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout" >

<SurfaceView 
    android:id="@+id/surface"
    android:layout_width="240px"
    android:layout_height="160px" />

<!--  A horizontal blue line --> 
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:background="@color/blue"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- A vertical blue line -->
    <View
    android:layout_width="1px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="12sp" 
            android:text="@string/about"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

To stop the system from restarting the activity, I have included this attribute to the activity tag in the manifest.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|keyboard|layoutDirection"
```

The surfaceview will be showing the camera preview.
I have to handle the orientation change without calling any methods on the Camera object ,i.e., the surface view should show the correct orientation of the camera preview without invoking `camera.setDisplayOrientation()`.

I tried to rotate the surfaceview in `onConfigurationChanged()`, but the surfaceview does not show the preview when rotated, but shows the preview only in the original orientation.